# Sharing std::string among the processes using Boost::Interprocess

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am following this [Boost::Interprocess guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html) . I have structure which has `std::string` as member and I have created multimap of that structure with `std::string` as key values.
I can access `std::string` from structure in producer code . But, when I try to access the same `std::string` member in consumer code then I am getting core dump.

Can some one help me. Thanks in advance. I am giving piece of code below :

Producer code :

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

struct temp
{
    int x;
    int y;
    std::string name;
};

    int main ()
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
   
    try
    {
        shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMultimap");

        managed_shared_memory segment
         (create_only
         ,"MySharedMultimap" //segment name
         ,65536);          //segment size in bytes


        typedef std::string KeyType;
        typedef struct temp MappedType;
        typedef std::pair<const std::string, struct temp> ValueType;

        typedef allocator< ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
            ShmemAllocator;


        typedef multimap<KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MyMultimap;

        //Initialize shared memory STL-compatible allocator
        const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

          //Construct a shared memory
        MyMultimap *mymultimap =
             segment.construct<MyMultimap>("MyMultimap") //object name
                                        (alloc_inst);//first ctor parameter

        std::string s = "key1";
        mymultimap->insert(std::pair<KeyType, MappedType>(s, t1));
    }
    catch(...)
    {
          shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMultimap");
          throw;
    }
}
```

Consumer code :

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>



struct temp
{
        int x;
        int y;
        std::string name;
};

    int main ()
   {
       using namespace boost::interprocess;
   
   try
   {
      managed_shared_memory segment
         (open_only
         ,"MySharedMultimap");  //segment name


      typedef std::string KeyType;
      typedef struct temp MappedType;
      typedef std::pair<const std::string, struct temp> ValueType;

      //Alias an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates ints from the managed
      //shared memory segment.  This allocator will allow to place containers
      //in managed shared memory segments
      typedef allocator<ValueType , managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
         ShmemAllocator;

      //Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator
      typedef multimap< KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>,  ShmemAllocator> MyMultimap;

      //Find the vector using the c-string name
      MyMultimap *mymultimap = segment.find<MyMultimap>("MyMultimap").first;

      std:: cout << " multimap size size : " << mymultimap->size() << std::endl;


      for(auto i = mymultimap->begin(); i != mymultimap->end(); ++i)
      {
        std::cout << i->first << std::endl;      // core dump ( as we are accessing std::string )

        std::cout << i->second.x << std::endl;  // works fine

        std::cout << i->second.name << std::endl;   // core dump ( as we are accessing std::string )
      }
    }
    catch(...){
      shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMultimap");
      throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `std::string` is essentially a wrapper around a `char` pointer. And pointers can't easily be shared between processes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's exactly the question: what needs to be done to make it work

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a shared-memory allocator. You already had the includes, why not use them?

First, I've simplified and combined your test programs into one: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e5d20e589f33309). **Note** this still has the same problem.

### Fixing The Problem

You need to use a string with shared memory allocator:

```
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
using Mgr     = Segment::segment_manager;

template <typename T>
using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Mgr>;

using String = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;
```

Now, use that:

```
struct temp {
    int    x;
    int    y;
    String name;
};
using MyMultimap = Multimap<String, temp>;
```

Which means you have to convert the `"more data"` as well:

```
// assume sa = String::allocator_type     sa(segment.get_segment_manager())

String more_data("more data", sa);
m.insert({String("key", sa), temp{1, 2, more_data}});
```

That works, **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/842ccaa0eda8e531)**, printing:

```
 multimap size size : 1
key
1
more data
```

### Solving The Annoying Allocators?

That's a lot of manual allocator juggling. Use scoped allocators to reduce that:

```
template <typename T>
using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;
```

Now you can write:

```
m.emplace("key", temp{1, 2, String("more data", sa)});
```

> To also propagate the allocator to the `temp::name` member, you need to make `temp` allocator-aware. `multimap` is not a suited example to show this with because its interface doesn't really exercise it anyways.
>
> For completeness, here's a sketch of what it might look like:
>
> ```
> struct temp {
>     using String         = Shared::String;
>     using allocator_type = String::allocator_type;
>
>     temp(temp const&) = default;
>     temp(temp&&)      = default;
>
>     temp(temp const& rhs, allocator_type a)
>         : x(rhs.x)
>         , y(rhs.y)
>         , name(rhs.name.data(), rhs.name.size(), a) {}
>
>     temp(temp&& rhs, allocator_type a) : temp(std::move(rhs)) {
>         if (a != name.get_allocator())
>             name = String(name.data(), name.size(), a);
>     }
>
>     template <typename Alloc>
>     temp(int x, int y, char const* name, Alloc a = {})
>         : x(x)
>         , y(y)
>         , name(name, a) {}
>
>     int    x;
>     int    y;
>     String name;
> };
> ```

### Heterogeneous Lookup

One step ahead of your question: you will probably want to `m.find("key")`, or `.lower_bound`,`.upper_bound` and `.equal_range`. To avoid the same allocator jumble and inefficiently allocating temporaries like so:

```
String::allocator_type sa(m.get_segment_manager());
auto r = m.equal_range(String("key", sa));
```

Use a transparant comparison:

```
using MyMultimap = Multimap<String, temp, std::less<>>;
```

Now you can "just" write:

```
// key lookup:
for (auto& [k, v] : boost::make_iterator_range(m.equal_range("key"))) {
    std::cout << k << "\n";
    std::cout << v.x    << "\n";
    std::cout << v.name << "\n";
}
```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/353230d562b6ab6a)**

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/container/scoped_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/container/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace Shared {
    namespace bc = boost::container;

#ifndef COLIRU
    using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
#else
    using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file;
#endif

    using Mgr    = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T>
    using Alloc = bc::scoped_allocator_adaptor<bip::allocator<T, Mgr>>;

    template <typename K, typename V, typename Cmp = std::less<K>>
    using Multimap = bc::multimap<K, V, Cmp, Alloc<std::pair<K const, V>>>;

    using String = bc::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char>>;

    static auto Remove = bip::shared_memory_object::remove;
} // namespace Shared

struct temp {
    using String         = Shared::String;
    using allocator_type = String::allocator_type;

    temp(temp const&) = default;
    temp(temp&&)      = default;

    temp(temp const& rhs, allocator_type a)
        : x(rhs.x)
        , y(rhs.y)
        , name(rhs.name.data(), rhs.name.size(), a) {}

    temp(temp&& rhs, allocator_type a) : temp(std::move(rhs)) {
        if (a != name.get_allocator())
            name = String(name.data(), name.size(), a);
    }

    template <typename Alloc>
    temp(int x, int y, char const* name, Alloc a = {})
        : x(x)
        , y(y)
        , name(name, a) {}

    int    x;
    int    y;
    String name;
};

int main(int argc, char** /*unused*/) {
    using namespace Shared;

    using MyMultimap        = Multimap<String, temp, std::less<>>;
    auto constexpr shm_name = "MySharedMemory";
    auto constexpr map_name = "MyMultimap";

    try {
        if (argc > 1) { // Producer
            Remove(shm_name);
            Segment segment(bip::create_only, shm_name, 65536);
            auto*   sm = segment.get_segment_manager();
            auto&   m  = *segment.construct<MyMultimap>(map_name) // object name
                       (sm); // first ctor parameter

            temp&& v{1, 2, "more data", sm};
            m.emplace("key", v);
        } else { // Consumer
            Segment segment(bip::open_only, shm_name);
            auto& m = *segment.find<MyMultimap>(map_name).first;

            std::cout << " multimap size size : " << m.size() << "\n";

            // key lookup:
            for (auto& [k, v] : boost::make_iterator_range(m.equal_range("key"))) {
                std::cout << k << "\n";
                std::cout << v.x    << "\n";
                std::cout << v.name << "\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
        // remove(name);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Running with e.g.

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lrt -DCOLIRU
./a.out producer
./a.out
```

Prints

```
 multimap size size : 1
key
1
more data
```